# Find the most common paths in R

Tags: r

I have data which looks similar to the follow. I have data on the user id, page number in the path, and the url of the visits site. I'm trying to find the most common paths taken.

```
df = data.frame(user_id = c(1,1,1,2,2), 
                page = c(1,2,3,1,2),
                url = c("x.com/home","x.com/home/about_us","x.com/directions",
                        "x.com/specials","x.com/contact_us"))
df
```

What are the most common paths? How would I go about finding that in R without utilizing any data mining algorithms. Is there a package for this?

By most common paths, I mean what were the url's that were most frequently visited. So for each user who went to 1, 2, 3, or 4 pages, what was the most frequently occuring path taken.

EDIT:

Example of output:

For all users who went to four page, here is the most common series of sites visited. This means these are the most common first, second, third, and fourth site visited.

```
   1   x.com/home
   2   x.com/home/about_us
   3   x.com/specials
   4   x.com/contact
```

If we had ten people who went to four pages, this was the most common 'path' (series of sites) visited in a session.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want with this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be possible to treat like a market basket analysis challenge. That is, what are the most common urls that visitors clicks, and if url A, then url B. To do this you need the library(arules). There is a good explanations at [prdeepakbabkus blog](http://prdeepakbabu.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/market-basket-analysisassociation-rule-mining-using-r-package-arules/)

For example, using your example (edited a bit), and made two more observations

```
library(arules)
data <- paste("1 x.com/home","1 x.com/home/about_us","2 x.com/home",
"2 x.com/home/about_us","3 x.com/home","4 x.com/specials", sep ="\n") 
cat(data)
write(data, file = "demo_single")
tr <- read.transactions("demo_single", format = "single", cols = c(1,2))
inspect(tr)
```

Now, you are ready to look at item frequency, and what most likely appears together

```
itemFrequencyPlot(tr);
basket_rules <- apriori(tr,parameter = list(sup = 0.5, conf = 0.9));
inspect(basket_rules);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you want. But if by the most visted , is the url that have the maximum number of page , you can do this :

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df,.(user_id),summarise,most.visisted =url[which.max(page)])
  user_id    most.visisted
1       1 x.com/directions
2       2 x.com/contact_us
```